# Ansible git clone as root

Tags: ansible

I'm using the following role for Ansible in order to clone a project in my vagrant setup:

```
- name: Clone Repository
   git: 
     repo: https://login:pwd@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git 
     dest: /home/vagrant/workspace/ 
     accept_hostkey: true
```

The cloning is working as expected, but the main issue is that the directory workspace and all it's content is now owned by root:

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 root    root    4096 Jun 10 12:35 workspace
```

I was thinking that those command were executed by 'vagrant' user as I defined in my playbook:

```
- hosts: vagrant
  sudo: yes 
  remote_user: vagrant
  roles:
    - git
```

Can you guys help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remote_user: vagrant` means that it will ssh into the host as user `vagrant`. `sudo: yes` means that before executing each task it will `sudo`, by default to root. You need to remove `sudo: yes`.

Answer (score 0):

---

- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - name: Clone Repository
    git:
    repo: https://github.com/code/json-server.git
    dest: /root/git

Comment: Could you format your answer, please?